# SQL Server Connection String on Domain

Tags: sql-server

I have a local SQL Server DB on my domain-attached machine to which I'm trying to connect via a WPF app. The original connstring was:

```
Server=MyMachine.MyDomain.local;Database=MyDomain;Trusted_Connection=True
```

That resulted in a failed connection (could connect via SSMS just fine), access is denied. When I changed the connstring to:

```
Server=MyMachine;Database=MyDomain;Trusted_Connection=True
```

everything connected properly. Any thoughts as to why? It's not a big deal, as it's a test db, but I'd like to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem: protocol TCP/IP was disabled, so it appears that calling it via MyMachine.MyDomain.local was trying to use the TCP/IP protocol, even though it was on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

It's a guess, but I'd bet that name resolution is failing. Somehow the dns lookup is failing, but the short name works because it tries a netbios lookup instead of a dns lookup. It likely also works if you put in the server IP address.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks; my big concern was that I'd configured SQL Server incorrectly on my machine or something like that.